# Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError couldn't find "libsiftrpixels.so Android Studio

Tags: android

> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/-1WyAeKK9WZsqHBHByIMadA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/-1WyAeKK9WZsqHBHByIMadA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/-1WyAeKK9WZsqHBHByIMadA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/-1WyAeKK9WZsqHBHByIMadA==/split_config.xhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/==/lib/arm64, /data/app/==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app//split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/==/split_config.xhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libsiftrpixels.so"

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]